# Is it possible to have more than one Wcf service class ? If yes then how?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Is it possible to have more than one Wcf service class . Because I have two contract interface and want to implement in two different service classes. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes - you just create two service classes and each of them implements that interface .... where's the issue??

Comment: I edited my question , Actually I have two different contract interface.

Comment: Again: yes - sure - what's the issue? `public class Service1 : IService1` and `public class Service2 : IService2` .....

Comment: Ok but when I tried through client , Service2 is not accessible.

Comment: You need to show us **more information** - what have you done? Where do you have an issue? This is still very unclear .....

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 contracts say IService1 and IService2, you have two options :

- both 2 service contracts are implemented by one service which implement all méthod from IService1 and IServe2. Then your configuration file will look like :

  ```
  <services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.Service">
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http:localhost:8080" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService1" />
          <endpoint address="Service2" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService2" />
      </service>
  </services>
  ```
- each contract is implemented by separate service let's say Service1 and Service2 then your configuration will look like :

  ```
  <services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.Service1">
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http:localhost:8081" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService1" />
      </service>
      <service name="MyNamespace.Service2">
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http:localhost:8082" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="Service2" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.IService2" />
      </service>
  </services>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but exposing those service is a different thing, you can't expose two contracts on a Single address(except if you wrap them in one single interface, not recommended). You need to give different endpoints to the two service contract in your web.config. Forexample,

```
 <services>
  <service name="TwoContracts.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TwoContracts.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://yoururl.com/TwoContracts/Service1" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="TwoContracts.Service2">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://yoururl.com/TwoContracts/Service2" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="TwoContracts.IService2" />
  </service>
</services>
```